# Extend google chrome element inspector with jquery data viewer

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I use firebug for javascript debug. But on large projects, he begins to stutter. In this regard, google chrome dev tools looks better - it's faster.

Firebuge have [fireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) to view all data which is stored in html element (by using [$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)).

How to see the same information in chrome element inspector?

I know solutions in console: "$('selector').data()". But it is not convenient. 
I want to see all html elements with stored data (like in "fireQuery").
s it possible to write a plugin for this functionality or is there some standard solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution (almost what i need): [Chrome Query](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-query/dbjmdgkkckmadopefnikhkpeaaojomaf) ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#chrome-query))

Answer (score 3):

Check out [jQuery Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi), too. Adds the same behavior as well as an overview of bound events.